# How to clear all filters when single click button in slick grid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I used the code below to load the slick grid inside the div tag, it's
working fine,but i want to play more functionalities in slick grid.
How can remove all filters in single button click?

---

```
function LoadSlickGrid(txtHRMFilter) {
        $(function () {
            //debugger;
            var data = [];


$.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/GetDetails/?strHRMFilter=' + txtHRMFilter,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            data = result.desc;

                        }
                    });



            var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();

            grid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", dataView, columns, options);

            grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());

            dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                grid.updateRowCount();
                grid.render();
            });

            dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
                grid.render();
            });

            dataView.beginUpdate();
            dataView.setItems(data);
            dataView.setFilter(filter);
            dataView.endUpdate();
            dataView.refresh();
            var filterPlugin = new Ext.Plugins.HeaderFilter({});

            filterPlugin.onFilterApplied.subscribe(function () {
                dataView.refresh();
                grid.resetActiveCell();

                var status;

                if (dataView.getLength() === dataView.getItems().length) {
                    status = "";
                } else {
                    status = dataView.getLength() + ' OF ' + dataView.getItems().length + ' RECORDS FOUND';
                }
                $('#status-label').text(status);

            });
            var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#pager"));
            filterPlugin.onCommand.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                dataView.fastSort(args.column.field, args.command === "sort-asc");
            });

            grid.registerPlugin(filterPlugin);

            var overlayPlugin = new Ext.Plugins.Overlays({});

            // Event fires when a range is selected
            overlayPlugin.onFillUpDown.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                var column = grid.getColumns()[args.range.fromCell];

                // Ensure the column is editable
                if (!column.editor) {
                    return;
                }

                var value = dataView.getItem(args.range.fromRow)[column.field];

                dataView.beginUpdate();

                for (var i = args.range.fromRow + 1; i <= args.range.toRow; i++) {
                    dataView.getItem(i)[column.field] = value;
                    grid.invalidateRow(i);
                }

                dataView.endUpdate();
                grid.render();
            });

            grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({ selectActiveRow: false }));
            grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);

            grid.registerPlugin(overlayPlugin);

            grid.init();

            function filter(item) {
                var columns = grid.getColumns();
                var value = true;

                for (var i = 0; i < columns.length`enter code here`; i++) {
                    var col = columns[i];
                    var filterValues = col.filterValues;

                    if (filterValues && filterValues.length > 0) {
                        value = value & _.contains(filterValues, item[col.field]);
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
        });
    }

--------------------------------
```

Now i want to clear all filters with single click button in slickgrid.

```
$("#btnclear").click(function () {
            ClearSlickGrid();
});
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set a blank filter:

```
$("#btnclear").click(function () {
    dataView.setFilter(function(item){
        return true;
    }
});
```

When you want to reapply your old filter just call:

```
dataView.setFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. when clicking "btnclear" button its working fine,but after i can't able to filter again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. when clicking "btnclear" button its working fine,but after i can't able to filter again. also filter icon was still visible after clearall filter.

Comment: Would you mind setting up a fiddle or sending a link to a live example? You would need to reassign your filter function when you wanted to filter again.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. whichever you said idea its working fine for clearing all filters. but after calling the "function LoadSlickGrid(txtHRMFilter) {..}" without page refresh the filter was not working, it default pass filter value has "True".so, i can't able to filter again after applying  """" $("#btnclear").click(function () {
    dataView.setFilter(function(item){
        return true;
    }
});"""" your function.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a live example? You're using several plugins and it's hard to tell what your goal is without seeing and running the full code— including the column definitions. It's unlikely that you want to create a new instance of the grid each time by calling LoadSlickGrid more than once on the page. To re-enable the filter on the page, you could have another button that calls dataView.setFilter(filter) in its handler, or even make the clear button a toggle.

Comment: Hi, After applying customer filter dataView.setFilter(function(item){
        return true;
    } It will clear all filter values but further i can't able to filter in slickgrid.

Comment: Please set up a https://jsfiddle.net/ with sample JSON data and any external resources for slick grid.